# How to ask someone to get another person's attention for me?

Tags: sentence-construction, usage, politeness

Say I want to talk to a person who I can not reach directly.
I want to ask the person sitting between us to get the other person's attention for me.
What should be a proper sentence to use here?
Can I say

> could you please get him for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong using

> Could you please get him for me

Commonly one would say

> Could you get him, please *(as you motion towards the person you want)*

There will also be situations when **nothing is said** and only **gesturing** occurs. For example, during an athletic event when noise levels are elevated.

Answer (score 2):

Formally:

> - "Excuse me, would you be so kind as to get So-And-So's attention for me, please? Cheers"

Or anything to that effect. It depends on how well you know the *Middle Man*.

Informally:

> - "Would you elbow So-And-So for me?"